# Skip kernel module at boot

Tags: linux, command-line, boot, kernel-module

There is a broken kernel module, due to which I can not even load the OS, so I can not delete or fix it. Is it possible to skip this module at boot, using the kernel's parameters or something?

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blacklisting the module as mentioned in the previous answer is the best way to completely avoid a kernel module.  Aside from blacklisting, there is no generic way to disable a module.

Some Linux distributions do provide kernel boot parameters to do things like this.

- [In Arch Linux](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Disabling_modules_auto-loading_with_the_load_modules_boot_parameter), `load_modules=off` forces udev to skip auto-loading.  This would allow you to boot without loading modules, blacklist a module that's causing trouble, and reboot normally without the troubled module loading.
- Knoppix has a long list of [extra boot parameters (aka "cheatcodes")](ftp://ftp.uni-kl.de/pub/linux/knoppix/knoppix-cheatcodes.txt); these are a mix of normal kernel boot parameters and Knoppix-specific extras.

For further info, see the [Kernel Parameters documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt). There are parameters for disabling specific subsystems.  For example:

- `nousb` disables kernel USB support
- `cgroup_disable=[name]` disables a particular controller; however, "memory" is the only example specifically supported
- `libata.noacpi` disables ACPI use in libata (SATA controllers); this is an example of passing a module parameter via the kernel

Answer (score 13):

Disabling specific modules *is* possible from boot loader, but looks like distro-dependent indeed.

On one hand, [Linux Kernel Parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt) documentations states, as of August 2016:

> `module_blacklist=`  [KNL] Do not load a comma-separated list of
>             modules.  Useful for debugging problem modules.

On the other hand, the option that worked for me with openSUSE 42.1 (Linux 4.1.31) is described in [Arch Kernel modules](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules#Using_kernel_command_line_2) wiki:

> You can also blacklist modules from the bootloader. Simply add
>
> `modprobe.blacklist=modname1,modname2,modname3`
>
> to your bootloader's kernel line, as described in Kernel parameters. When you are blacklisting more than one module, note that they are separated by commas only. Spaces or anything else might presumably break the syntax.

(Thanks to @gertvdijk at [unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59256/94120) for pointing this out.)

Also worth to mention is [the following method](https://remote-lab.net/blacklisting-kernel-modules):

> In order the prevent certain modules from being loaded by the kernel using the grub command line you need to pass them as a parameter to the kernel line using the below syntax.
>
> `$module_name.blacklist=yes`

I have no idea where did they get that from, but it will definitely not hurt to try any other method if all else fails.

Comment: I have the same question on why "$module_name.blacklist=yes" works, and I think it is related to this part of kernel code: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/kernel/params.c?h=v3.2.96#n786

Comment: Only the first one worked for me in LMDE 5 (Debian 11). I remember the third option working in EndeavourOS (Arch)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to either add it to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist, or blacklist 'modulename'

Comment: this will work but requires booting to another kernel (if available) or a LiveCD system.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu, you can press Escape or Shift at boot which will bring you to the grub menu.
There, choose advanced options, pick your kernel and then "drop to root prompt".
You can blacklist your module by putting it in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`.
Ctrl+D to go back into the grub menu once you're done.
"Resume" to resume the boot process.

Comment: Unfortunately for me the kernel already crashes when dropping to root prompt, so I need a way to disable the bad module (iwlwifi) from grub.

Answer (score 0):

At Grub 2, I was adding (typing in) a command

```
 modprobe.blacklist=radeon
```

to blacklist radeon graphics module/driver which did not work on my laptop, and it worked.

(Press Tab when GRUB 2 menu appears  to add parameters.)

(Do not forget a space before modprobe.blacklist!)

(Details: I was booting from Live USB to install Linux Mint, but this is not very important here.)